# json.Unmarshal не получается

Tags: json, golang

Если от клиента из браузера

```
xhr.send(j);
```

получаю аяксом строку:

```
j := `{"m": 1, "n": 3, "d": ["22032022", 12.59, 215]}`
```

То не получается вынуть данные массива, делаю так:

```
type Inner struct {
    A string   //`json:"A"`
    B float64  //`json:"B"`
    C float64  //`json:"C"`
}

type Outer struct {
    M int8
    N int16
    Data Inner
}

var res Outer

err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(j), &res)
if err != nil {
// print error
fmt.Println(err)
}

fmt.Println("M00: ", j)           //  {"m": 1, "n": 6, "d": ["22032022", 12.59, 215]}
fmt.Println("M01: ", res.M)       //  1
fmt.Println("M02: ", res.N)       //  6
fmt.Println("M03: ", res.Data.A)  //
fmt.Println("M04: ", res.Data.B)  //  0
fmt.Println("M05: ", res.Data.C)  //  0
fmt.Println("M06: ", res)         //  {1 6 { 0 0  }}
```

Хочу получить (М03:,М04:,М05:) именно из приведенного массива, а не из:

```
["A":"22032022", "B":12.59, "C":215]
```

хотя с тэгами, - тоже не получилось ..
help, please

Comment: Потому что у вас массив [вместо объекта](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38861295/how-to-parse-json-arrays-with-two-different-data-types-into-a-struct-in-golang) для значения d.

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov, спасибо, - читаю ..

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov, Да, по ссылке получилось сделать (пример от @Dale). Вы мне здорово помог-ли. Thanks.

Comment: Если у вас заранее неизвестна структура объекта, лучше декодировать объект в `map[string]interface{}`, а затем ручками разбирать полученные ключи и значения

Comment: @Pak Uula, а если известна и в том виде, - который привёл в примере?

Comment: Тогда вариант из вашего ответа вполне рабочий. `json.Unmarshal` десериализует массив JSON только в массив Go, и никак не в структуру. Если вам нужно более сложное преобразование, то нужно писать отдельный декодер `func (*Outer)UnmarshalJSON([]byte) error` для реализации типа [`json.Unmarshaler`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshaler)

Answer (score 0):

Получилось решить только так, см. [The Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/IeLCfuy2AyF)

```
j := `{"m": 1, "n": 3, "d": ["22032022", 12.59, 215]}`

type Outer struct {
    M int8
    N int16
    D [3]interface{}
}

var res Outer

err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(j), &res)
if err != nil {
    // print error
    fmt.Println(err)
}

fmt.Println("M00: ", j)        //  {"m": 1, "n": 6, "d": ["22032022", 12.59, 215]}
fmt.Println("M01: ", res.M)    //  1
fmt.Println("M02: ", res.N)    //  3
fmt.Println("M03: ", res.D[0]) //  22032022
fmt.Println("M04: ", res.D[1]) //  12.59
fmt.Println("M05: ", res.D[2]) //  215
fmt.Println("M06: ", res)      //  {1 6 { 22032022 12.59 215 }}
```

Не получается загрузить массив ["22032022", 12.59, 215] в структуру Inner, пришлось ее убрать и использовать массив [3]interface{}